# Is it possible to delete all contents from a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook-groups, delete

I’m the administrator of a private group on Facebook and I need to delete all posts and pictures from this year, to start new contents. Is it possible to do it all at once or do I have to do it one by one?

Answer (score 2):

To delete a group secret or public you have to remove each user one by one. To remove posts too you have to delete individually. IMO there is no other method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it one by one. Or you could delete the group, but that requires removing all users from the group.

Alternatively just create a page. In this way you will have timeline available, and thus have a better way of organizing your stuff.

Comment: This is not true that you have to delete people in a group "one-by-one" I am in the process of deleting thousands and deleting the group. If you're not tech-savvy don't speak as if you are. Nothing is impossible. YOU just don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Anon: If you know how to do it, then please explain it in an answer for the benefit of others.